# how to get Data from sqlite table using where Cluase in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite

I am selecting data from two tables in normal condition it works fine but if i use where clause it does not return anything.

here is the query

```
NSString *select =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT *from ContentMaster As ml LEFT JOIN ContentTagging As cat ON cat.ContentID = ml.ContentID where cat.ContenTagText= %@" , appDelegate.tagInput];
```

Here is the NSLog of query

```
SELECT *from ContentMaster As ml LEFT JOIN ContentTagging  ON cat.ContentID = ml.ContentID where cat.ContenTagText= Tag1
```

Comment: have you execute this query in sqllite? has It return any value? if yes than check if appDelegate.tagInput has some value in it. print the    select query and check it for correction

Comment: yes i have print the appDelegate.tagInput it has value and querry result is also shows here is the result SELECT *from ContentMaster As ml LEFT JOIN ContentTagging  ON cat.ContentID = ml.ContentID where cat.ContenTagText= Tag1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your ContenTagText in `''` as it is comparing the string

```
NSString *select =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from ContentMaster As ml LEFT JOIN ContentTagging As cat ON cat.ContentID = ml.ContentID where cat.ContenTagText= \'%@\'" , appDelegate.tagInput];
```

The query will be:

```
SELECT *from ContentMaster As ml LEFT JOIN ContentTagging  ON cat.ContentID = ml.ContentID where cat.ContenTagText= 'Tag1'
```

hope it will help.

Comment: any idea if i want to also get the ContentTagText from ContentTagging then how to add that in this

Comment: you can try with "SELECT *,ct. ContentTagText as contenttext from  ContentTagging as ct,ContentMaster As ml .... "

Comment: first check my query in sqllite for any typo mistake :)